# how to implement react native google places auto complete in modalview

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I implemented react native google places in modalview. But it is working when navigating as separate screen. In modalview view getting drop down list but unable to get the data when onpressed.
I followed this link. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-places-autocomplete